# Struts logic tag problem

Tags: struts, logic, tags

i know this doesnt work but i dont know why, also how can i make it work?

```
 <% int result = referer.indexOf("smlMoverDetail.do"); %>

 <% if (result == -1){%> 
 <%out.print("checking");%>
 <bean:define id="JOININGDATE" name="smlMoverDetailForm"
 property="empFDJoiningDate" type="java.lang.String" toScope="session"/>
 <%}%>
```

Please please help i dont understand

i have tried this

```
<logic:Equal name="result"   value = "-1">
<bean:define id="JOININGDATE" name="smlMoverDetailForm"
 property="empFDJoiningDate" type="java.lang.String" toScope="session"/>
</logic:Equal>
```

but that doenst work either it doesnt exicute the bean:define part

help
thansk

Answer (score 1):

Guess this was just a typing error, but the Equal in

```
<logic:Equal name="result"   value = "-1">
```

should actually be

```
<logic:equal name="result"   value = "-1">
```

The case could be the reason why the error is occurring.

Of course, it would help if you could tell us what error you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

It would help a lot if you say what the code actually does. I can see what you are trying to do, but what is actually happening? Any errors? Does it print out "checking"?